# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (getting this error on multiple async/await calls)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

On using multiple async/await i am getting error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I think the stack size is fulled on calling so many async functions but if not so how do i achieve same functionality that this code would have achieved if it doesn't get any error

Code attached below:

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Rides = () => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [updatedRides, setUpdatedRides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRides = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/rides');
      const json = await data.json();
  
      setRides(json);
      setUpdatedRides(json);
    }

    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/user');

      const json = await data.json();

      setUser(json);
    }

    const calculateDistance = (path, user_station) => {
      let min = Math.abs(user_station - path[0]);
      for(let i = 0; i<path.length; i++){
        if(path[i] === user_station){
          return 0;
        }
        if(Math.abs(path[i] - user_station) < min){
          min = Math.abs(path[i] - user_station);
        }
      }
      return min;
    }
    
    const fetch = async() => {
      await fetchRides();
      await fetchUser();

      updatedRides.map((ride) => {
        ride.distance = calculateDistance(ride.station_path, user.station_code);
      })
    }

    fetch().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })

  }, [])

  return(
    <div>
      <Navbar user = {user}/>
      <div className="rides">
        {updatedRides.map((ride) => {
          return (
            <div className="rideDetail">
              <img src = {ride.map_url} alt="Ride_map" />
              <div>
                <p>Ride Id : {ride.id}</p>
                <p>Origin Station : {ride.origin_station_code}</p>
                <p>Station Path : {ride.station_path}</p>
                <p>Date : {ride.date}</p>
                <p>Distance : {ride.distance}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Rides;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nice and legible, but even so, it's a little bit hard to tell what you're going for:

A major issue is that the function you define called "fetch" (side note: [shadowing](https://mayuminishimoto.medium.com/understanding-variable-shadowing-with-javascript-58fc108c8f03#:%7E:text=Variable%20shadowing%20refers%20to%20the,defined%20in%20the%20outer%20scope.) variable names is frowned upon), is not returning a variable or setting state (so it's not really doing anything).

Another issue is that `updateRides` in your `fetch` function will be stale (have the initial value, not the one set by `fetchRides`). That may mean you're looping over data in a different format (or at least different values) than you're expecting.

I think this might be a little closer (let me know if it's not and I can update):

```js
const Rides = () => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRides = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/rides');
      const json = await data.json();

      return json;
    }

    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/user');

      const json = await data.json();

      setUser(json);
    }

    const calculateDistance = (path, user_station) => {
      let min = Math.abs(user_station - path[0]);
      for(let i = 0; i<path.length; i++){
        if(path[i] === user_station){
          return 0;
        }
        if(Math.abs(path[i] - user_station) < min){
          min = Math.abs(path[i] - user_station);
        }
      }
      return min;
    }
    
    const makeNetworkCalls = async() => {
      const rides = await fetchRides();
      await fetchUser();

      setRides(updatedRides.map((ride) => {
        ride.distance = calculateDistance(ride.station_path, user.station_code);
      }))
    }

    makeNetworkCalls().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })

  }, [])
```

Comment: A major issue is that the function you define called "fetch" (side note: shadowing variable names is frowned upon): I think this was the major issue and after changing this the error is gone